# Spark SQL in YARN: OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

## Problem description

I'm trying to query data from ORC files which are stored in HDFS with Spark SQL. When I am working with small data volumes (2-5 Gb), I don't face any issues. However, in case I'm trying to process over 400 Gb I have an error on my executors.

What is the root cause of an issue - driver code or cluster configuration?

```
21/08/09 14:28:35 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 70.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 90) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderUtils.readDiskRanges(RecordReaderUtils.java:565)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderUtils$DefaultDataReader.readFileData(RecordReaderUtils.java:285)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.readAllDataStreams(RecordReaderImpl.java:1147)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.readStripe(RecordReaderImpl.java:1103)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.advanceStripe(RecordReaderImpl.java:1256)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.advanceToNextRow(RecordReaderImpl.java:1291)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.<init>(RecordReaderImpl.java:286)
        at org.apache.orc.impl.ReaderImpl.rows(ReaderImpl.java:669)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.initialize(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat.$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1(OrcFileFormat.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcFileFormat$$Lambda$1041/844883412.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FileSourceScanExec$$anon$1.hasNext(DataSourceScanExec.scala:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.columnartorow_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.DefaultCachedBatchSerializer$$anon$1.hasNext(InMemoryRelation.scala:118)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:299)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.$anonfun$doPutIterator$1(BlockManager.scala:1423)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$Lambda$585/222823930.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doPut(BlockManager.scala:1350)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1414)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:1237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:384)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
```

Code of my Spark driver and environment configuration is given below.

## Code

I use the following code:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate();

spark.read()
     .option(MERGE_SCHEMA_OPTION, true)
     .orc("/path/to/folder/with/orc/group/by/partition")
     .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK()))
     .createOrReplaceTempView("viewName");

spark.sql("SELECT * FROM viewName WHERE KEY IN ('2021-08-01', '2021-08-02') AND time >= '2021-08-01T00:00:00.000Z' AND time <= '2021-08-02T23:59:59.000Z' AND code > 400")
      .write()
      .orc(properties.getResultLocation();
```

In my solution I used all operators like **WHERE** and **KEY IN** in SQL string. As query structure depends on many parameters, it is the easiest way to build a query.

## Data description

Data is presented as **.ORC* files with the following schema:

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| message | string |
| code | int |
| rate | double |
| time | timestamp |

All files with data are stored in partition folders named after **time** value field:

```
.
├── /path/to/folder/with/orc/group/by/partition
│   └──key=2021-08-01
│       ├── part_1.orc
│       ├── part_2.orc
│       └── part_...
│   └── key=2021-08-02
│       ├── part_1.orc
│       ├── part_2.orc
│       └── part_...
│   └── key=...
│       ├── ...
│       └── ...
```

For testing purposes I used ~400 GB of data (1.2 TB disk space consumed).

## Environment configuration

I'm running my application in YARN cluster, which contains 3 Node Managers with the following configuration:

| RAM | Cores |
| --- | --- |
| 16 Gb | 8 |

I submit my application with properties:

| Property | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `spark.executors.cores` | 5 |
| `spark.executor.memory` | 14 Gb |
| `spark.yarn.executor.memory.overhead` | 2 Gb |
| `spark.driver.memory` | 14 Gb |
| `spark.driver.cores` | 5 |
| `spark.executor.instances` | 2 |
| `spark.default.parallelism` | 20 |
| `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` | -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:UseCompressedOops |
| `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` | -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:UseCompressedOops |

Spark version - **3.1.2**
YARN version - **3.0.0-cdh6.1.1**

Answer (score 0):

with compression your 400GB of orc file can be 1.6TB or more of data. Also the parallelism is 20 so each executor is likely to get ~ 1/20 of the data (depending on how much of your query can be pushed down to prevent reading data into memory) - it might be likely that the amount of data that an executor with 14GB needs to read a chunk that is larger than its working memory

Try to increase parallelism and/or the memory in the executors (you may want to add executors as well).